# I don't understand the concept of this function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

for example, you would have

```
<input id="searchbox" type="text" value="Type Here..." />

<button id="clickbait">Click Me</button>

<div id="emptydiv">sda</div>


<script type="text/javascript">


var clickthis="clickbait";
var searchinput=document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
var generate="emptydiv";


    document.getElementById(clickthis).onclick=function () {
        searchinput=document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
        document.getElementById(generate).innerHTML=searchinput;
    }

</script>
```

So this is pretty much just something to change the text in the empty div to whatever is in the text field when you click on the button but I don't understand the "idea" of what's going on here. I already set the var to a value so why do you need to grab the value again?

I can understand the other basics so far like document(refers to the whole page) then getelementbyid(refers to the element) and then on the click you want it to perform a function but everything after that is confusing.

Comment: Which line exactly you don't understand?

Comment: this line - searchinput=document.getElementById("searchbox").value; I already defined the value in var so why am i referring to it again?

Comment: As I see it, it is just a simple demo without much use, showing how you can retrieve and assign data from/to different html elements

Comment: @IbtedaSabur Set the variable `searchinput` with the value of the `<input />` with an `id` of `searchbox`. Does it help?

Comment: The line you aren't understanding is executing inside of an event handler, so it is grabbing the value a second time in case it has changed.

Comment: The function Basically extracting value from the input field #clickbait and setting  it inside a element "emptydiv".

Comment: You are fetching the value again because it will probably have changed between the time the page loaded and the time the user clicked on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already set the var to a value so why do you need to grab the value
>   again?

When you set the `searchinput` value first before the onclick assignment, you fetched and assigned the value of `searchinput` at that time.

Inside the click event handler, you are getting the value in `searchinput` **when the div is clicked** so the value at that time might be different.

Comment: ohh alright it makes sense now lol I'm mad it was that simple though

Answer (score 1):

When its firing click event then   searchinput=document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
that means searachinput is what everever typed in the input feild

and then  that value is being reassigned to 
document.getElementById(generate).innerHTML=searchinput;

Answer (score 0):

```
`
```

When the button is clicked fire the event:

```
document.getElementById(clickthis).onclick=function ()
```

Get the value of 'searchBox':

```
searchinput=document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
```

Assign what ever was in the 'searchBox' as HTML in 'emptyDiv'

```
document.getElementById(generate).innerHTML=searchinput;
```

Just to note that:

```
searchinput=document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
```

Is actually redundant because you are already declaring it with the other vars.

So your code should look like this:

```
    document.getElementById('clickbait').onclick=function () {
        var searchinput = document.getElementById("searchbox").value;
        document.getElementById('emptydiv).innerHTML=searchinput;
    }
```

Or to make it even simpler and cut it down to 2 lines you could even use jQuery:

```
$('#clickbait').on('click', function(){
   $('#emptydiv').innerHTML = $('#searchbox').value;
}
```

Comment: cool thnx man, I didn't even know you could do that, I was just following the format that I saw. I don't know jquery anyway

Answer (score -3):

It copies the value of input into the "emptydiv" div when you click on the button.

Why is the real good question, here, IMO.

Comment: This should have been a comment, IMO.

Comment: yea that's what i was asking

Comment: Comments on initial post needs some reputation. As the original question is "what is the concept of this function", a full answer seems more appropriate.